# How to add custom tinymce plugin to new text widget

Tags: widgets, tinymce, wysiwyg, plugin-tinymce, widget-text

So I have a custom TinyMCE plugin, which adds a button to the editor.

I'm using the *mce_external_plugins* and *mce_buttons* filter to add my TinyMCE plugin.

After WP 4.8 introduced the simple TinyMCE for the new text widget i would like to include my button i that editor as well. For some reason i can't seem to find any documentation the the widget editor in terms of modification and including additional features.

Have any of you guys had any luck modifying the widget editor? Or have you seen any documentation for custom plugins for it?

Comment: You need to do it with Javascript. The announcement post for the change has more details: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/23/addition-of-tinymce-to-the-text-widget/

Comment: Thanks i figured it out from the article. I just used admin_enqueue_scripts to load the additional jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with help from Jacob Peattie and the article from https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/23/addition-of-tinymce-to-the-text-widget/

Here's a quick walkthrough on what i did:

I made a new js file container the code of my original button, but modified it to the event listener of the widget tinymce

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'tinymce-editor-setup', function( event, editor ) {
editor.settings.toolbar1 += ',bbh_custom_mce_button';
var pathname = window.location.hostname;
var protocol = window.location.protocol
editor.addButton( 'bbh_custom_mce_button', {
    title: 'Insert button',
    image: protocol + '//' + pathname + '/wp-content/themes/brandbyhand/include/tinymce-button/button-sharpen.png',
    onclick: function() {
        editor.windowManager.open( {
            title: 'Insert button',
            body: [
                {
                    type: 'textbox',
                    name: 'text',
                    label: 'Button text'
                },
                {
                    type: 'textbox',
                    name: 'link',
                    label: 'Button link',
                    class: 'custom-link',

                    onkeydown: function( event ){
                        var link = jQuery(event.target).val();
                        var windowID = event.currentTarget.id;
                        jQuery(event.target).addClass('custom-link-' + windowID);



                        /*if(link.indexOf('mailto:') === -1 && link.indexOf('tel:') === -1){
                            link = (link.indexOf('://') === -1) ? 'http://' + link : link;    
                        }

                        jQuery(event.target).val(link);*/
                    },
                    onfocusout: function( event ){
                        var link = jQuery(event.target).val();

                        var windowID = event.currentTarget.id;
                        jQuery(event.target).addClass('custom-link-' + windowID);

                        if(link.indexOf('mailto:') === -1 && link.indexOf('tel:') === -1){
                            link = (link.indexOf('://') === -1) ? 'http://' + link : link;    
                        }

                        jQuery(event.target).val(link);
                    }
                },
                {
                    type   : 'listbox',
                    name   : 'style',
                    label  : 'Button style',
                    values : [
                        { text: 'Empty', value: 'ghost' },
                        { text: 'Filled', value: 'filled' },
                    ],
                    value : 'style1' // Sets the default
                },
                {
                    type   : 'checkbox',
                    name   : 'target',
                    label  : 'Open link in a new tab',
                    checked : false

                }
            ],
            onsubmit: function( e ) {
                e.stopPropagation();

                var windowID = e.target._eventsRoot._id;


                var link = jQuery('.custom-link-' + windowID).val();

                if(link.indexOf('mailto:') === -1 && link.indexOf('tel:') === -1){
                    link = (link.indexOf('://') === -1) ? 'http://' + link : link;
                }

                jQuery('.custom-link-' + windowID).val(link);


                var target = '_self';
                if(e.data.target === true){
                    target = '_blank';
                } else if(e.data.target === false){
                    target = '_self'
                }

                editor.insertContent( '<span class="clearfix"><a class="btn btn-custom ' + e.data.style + '" target="' + target + '" href="' + link + '">' + e.data.text + '</a></span>' );
                editor.windowManager.close();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

I then enqueued that file using the admin_enqueue_scripts hook:

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
if ( 'widgets.php' != $hook ) {
    return;
}

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce_custom_button_widget', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tinymce_widget.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tinymce_custom_button_widget_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/include/tinymce-button/custom-editor-style.css', '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

And thats basically it.